# Confused how to assign value at index to another value at index to another value at index from a list

Tags: java, list, indexing

Let's say the code is:

```
int[] a = {0,1,2,3};
        a[0]=a[2]=a[1];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i]+ " ");
        }
```

Why does it print "1 1 1 3" and not "2 1 1 3"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

When multiple assignments occur in one statement, these assignments have right-associativity.  This means that

```
a[0]=a[2]=a[1];
```

has the same meaning as:

```
a[0]=(a[2]=a[1]);
```

[JLS Section 15.26 details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26):

> There are 12 *assignment operators*; all are syntactically right-associative (they group right-to-left). Thus, `a=b=c` means `a=(b=c)`, which assigns the value of `c` to `b` and then assigns the value of `b` to `a`.
>
> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred.

So, the end result of one assignment is the value that was assigned.  This means that:

1. The value at `a[1]` gets assigned to `a[2]`, which is `1`.  This is the value of the expression `a[2]=a[1]`.
2. The value from step (1), `1`, gets assigned to `a[0]`.

If you want the value from `a[2]` to get assigned to `a[0]` before copying the value from `a[1]` to `a[2]`, then you must break them up into separate statements.

```
a[0]=a[2];
a[2]=a[1];
```